# Could someone explain how to form the genitive partitive in German? (Einer meiner wording)

Tags: genitive, possessive

I know that the translation to "one of my friends" is always formed by "ein-" as the indefinite pronoun meaning "one" and a possessive pronoun whatsoever in the genitive. I couldn't find however much in the internet or in books about how does one properly "inflects" the "ein-" in accordance to all the cases and genders. Could someone help me out with filling and correcting this table?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: What's the plural to "one"?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**männlich:**

- Nominativ

  > **Einer** meiner Söhne ist im Haus.
  >   **One** of my sons is in the house.
- Genitiv

  > Das ist das Haus **eines** meiner Söhne.
  >   This is the house of **one** of my sons.
- Dativ

  > Dieses Buch gehört **einem** meiner Söhne.
  >   This book belongs to **one** of my sons.
- Akkusativ

  > Ich sehe **einen** meiner Söhne.
  >   I see **one** of my sons.

**weiblich:**

- Nominativ

  > **Eine** meiner Töchter ist im Haus.
  >   **One** of my daughters is in the house.
- Genitiv

  > Das ist das Haus **einer** meiner Töchter.
  >   This is the house of **one** of my daughters.
- Dativ

  > Dieses Buch gehört **einer** meiner Töchter.
  >   This book belongs to **one** of my daughters.
- Akkusativ

  > Ich sehe **eine** meiner Töchter.
  >   I see **one** of my daughters.

**sächlich:**

- Nominativ

  > **Eines** meiner Kinder ist im Haus. (**Eins** meiner Kinder ist im Haus.)
  >   **One** of my children is in the house.
- Genitiv

  > Das ist das Haus **eines** meiner Kinder.
  >   This is the house of **one** of my children.
- Dativ

  > Dieses Buch gehört **einem** meiner Kinder.
  >   This book belongs to **one** of my children.
- Akkusativ

  > Ich sehe **eines** meiner Kinder. (Ich sehe **eins** meiner Kinder.)
  >   I see **one** of my children.

**Mehrzahl:**

In German the indefinite pronoun *»ein«* has no plural (same in English, where *"one"* has no plural). So the declination table in your question is wrong. For plural you must use another indefinite pronoun like *»alle«* (*"all"* in English), *»einige«* (*"some"*) or *»viele«* (*"many"*). In my examples, I use *»einige«*:

- Nominativ

  > **Einige** meiner Söhne sind im Haus.
  >   **Some** of my sons are in the house.
- Genitiv

  > Das sind die Häuser **einiger** meiner Söhne.
  >   These are the houses of **some** of my sons.
- Dativ

  > Diese Bücher gehören **einigen** meiner Söhne.
  >   These books belongs to **some** of my sons.
- Akkusativ

  > Ich sehe **einige** meiner Söhne.
  >   I see **some** of my sons.

---

Note, that the possessive pronoun (*»meiner«* in the examples above) doesn't depend on the object, but on the "owner" of the sons, daughters, children, friends etc.:

- 1. Person Einzahl:

     > Einer **meiner** Söhne ist im Haus.
     >   One of **my** sons is in the house.
- 2. Person Einzahl, Du-Form:

     > Einer **deiner** Söhne ist im Haus.
     >   One of **your** sons is in the house.
- 2. Person Einzahl, Sie-Form:

     > Einer **Ihrer** Söhne ist im Haus.
     >   One of **your** sons is in the house.
- 3. Person Einzahl, männlich:

     > Einer **seiner** Söhne ist im Haus.
     >   One of **his** sons is in the house.
- 3. Person Einzahl, weiblich:

     > Einer **ihrer** Söhne ist im Haus.
     >   One of **her** sons is in the house.
- 3. Person Einzahl, sächlich:

     > Einer **seiner** Söhne ist im Haus.
     >   One of **its** sons is in the house.
- 1. Person Mehrzahl:

     > Einer **unserer** Söhne ist im Haus.
     >   One of **our** sons is in the house.
- 2. Person Mehrzahl, Du-Form:

     > Einer **eurer** Söhne ist im Haus.
     >   One of **your** sons is in the house.
- 2. Person Mehrzahl, Sie-Form:

     > Einer **Ihrer** Söhne ist im Haus.
     >   One of **your** sons is in the house.
- 3. Person Mehrzahl:

     > Einer **ihrer** Söhne ist im Haus.
     >   One of **their** sons is in the house.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I had a really hard time figuring out how I would use this wording in plural; now it is clear to me, as well as its other uses. I bet it will help other learners too seeking for this information.

Comment: Die Tabelle ist perfekt. Hier eine Anmerkung zum Gebrauch: In der Umgangssprache ist in vielen Fällen der Genitiv nicht beliebt und kann angestrengt-bildungssprachlich wirken. Ausweichkonstruktion wäre hier z.B. 'ein Freund von mir'. Bei Familienangehörigen erscheint mir wiederum auch die von-Konstruktion ungehörig, allenfalls salopp umgangssprachlich. Da auch hier je nachdem der Genitiv eine Spur akademisch 'rüberkommen' kann, würde man in vielen Fällen so etwas sagen wie 'mein jüngster Sohn' oder 'mein Jüngster', 'meine Zweitälteste' usw. Es gibt etliche weitere Ersatzmöglichkeiten.